# Get web content

Tags: java, android

I'm trying to get XML content from an URL:

```
HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
HttpGet request = new HttpGet();
request.setURI(new URI("http://www.domain.com/test.aspx"));
HttpResponse response = client.execute(request);
in = response.getEntity().getContent();
```

When I write out the response content, this is truncated before the end of the content.

Any idea?

Answer (score 1):

Did you use a `InputStreamReader` for the input stream `in`?

```
String s = "";
String line = "";
BufferedReader rd = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(in));
try {
    while ((line = rd.readLine()) != null) { s += line; }
} catch (IOException e) {
    // Handle error
}

// s should be the complete string
```

Comment: i pass the input stream to parse method of DocumentBuilder class.

Answer (score 0):

maybe i have solved, was the android emulator. Simply restarting it all works fine.

Thanks to all